# zsh - Include directories in glob loop

Tags: zsh, glob

I have the following `zsh` script which symlinks all files in a given directory (except `README.md`) to my home directory with a leading `.` in front of each file name.

```
setopt EXTENDED_GLOB
for rcfile in "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}"/.dotfiles/home/^README.md(.N); do
  ln -fsv "$rcfile" "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.${rcfile:t}"
done
```

The problem is that the glob doesn't seem to include any directories inside `"${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}"/.dotfiles/home/`, just regular files. How can I include directories in this loop (so, for example, the directory `/Users/user/.dotfiles/home/vim` is symlinked to `/Users/user/.vim`)? I've tried some things with `find` but I'd prefer to stick to pure `zsh` scripting if possible.

For reference, here's the listing of this directory:

```
README.md
gitconfig
tmux.conf
vim
vimrc
zlogin
zprofile
zshenv
zshrc
```

And here's the value of each iteration of the loop:

```
/Users/user/.dotfiles/home/gitconfig
/Users/user/.dotfiles/home/tmux.conf
/Users/user/.dotfiles/home/vimrc
/Users/user/.dotfiles/home/zlogin
/Users/user/.dotfiles/home/zprofile
/Users/user/.dotfiles/home/zshenv
/Users/user/.dotfiles/home/zshrc
```

So `README.md` is excluded, as I intended, but `vim` is also excluded but I would like it (and any other directories) to be included.

Comment: I think you have to define ZDOTDIR assigning it a value like
    ZDOTDIR=~/.dotfiles  or someting similar, otherwise zsh will set $HOME to it. Other problem is: Don't forget to do the procedure in zsh instead of bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.` in the globbing qualifier (`(.N)`) of the pattern you use for your loop restricts the matches to plain files (no directories, no symlinks, etc.). Just leave it out and it will also find directories (or any other file type).

For more information on globbing and globbing qualifiers, have a look at `man 1 zshexpn`. Or online at the [ZSH Documentation on Filename Generation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation) ([here is the subsection on Glob Qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers))

You will also need to add the option `-n` to `ln`, otherwise the symbolic links will be put into the linked directory instead of overwriting the link itself.

So this should work as expected:

```sh
setopt EXTENDED_GLOB
for rcfile in "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}"/.dotfiles/home/^README.md(N); do
  ln -fsnv "$rcfile" "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.${rcfile:t}"
done
```

Comment: Excellent, many thanks. I've looked around for information on `zsh`'s extended glob syntax but couldn't find much information. Do you have a link to something that can explain everything?

Comment: zsh has a quite extensive documentation, which you can either access as manpages (`man zshall` to get everything at once) or [online](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/). I also added the relevant links to the answer.